# How to make ionic app push() to TabsPage upon Login

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have a login system set up in Firebase and Ionic 2. I started my app with a Tabs template and I'm trying to make it so that when the user logs in they are directed to the TabsPage.

When I try to use this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage'); it give me an Promise error.

Here is my Login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from "../../models/user";
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  user = {} as User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: 
NavController, 
public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  async login(user: User){
  try{
    const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, 
user.password);
      if(result){
      this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage');
      }
    }
    catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    }
  }

  register(){
  this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage')` to `await this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage')`

And make the register function `async` and add `await` in front of it too.

Comment: omg i was messing with is for so long... you're a legend! thanks